# Calling an Asyc Task<T> method

Tags: c#, async-await, win-universal-app, task, windows-10-universal

I'm learning async (UWP) methods right now and can't quite get my head around the syntax.  All the examples have a lot more going on than just the Task async calls and don't really show how they initiate.  The main thing I don't understand is how to initiate the task from a non async method.  Everytime I try to call the task, it wants me to convert that method to an async one. Which in turn would want me to turn any method that calls that one to async.  So how are you supposed to start it?

The current use case I am trying is to retrieve a JSON file full of user names and Ids from UWP localstorage which now in UWP is an async call.  I'm pretty sure my Method is correct but I am having problems calling it. Currently I'm calling the method in the code behind of the page it is supporting, where the actual method currently resides in the User Class.

here is the code I have:

```
public async Task<List<User>> getUsers()
    {
        List<User> u = new List<User>();
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("LocalUsers.txt");
        string Json = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        List<User> existingUsers = new List<User>();
        existingUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(Json);
        return existingUsers;
    }
```

and this is how I was attempting to call the method from the code behind

```
    List<User> users = await User.getUsers();
```

I've tried running Tasks too like this, but I don't think my sytax is right or something

```
    Task t = new Task(User.getUsers());
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreaciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why not make the consuming method `async`, as recommended?

Comment: That is probably what I will do in the future, but it seemed that async would just keep creeping further and further into the code and I didn't think that was the correct course but as others have pointed out this is in fact the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to make the calling method async then following would do

```
List<User> users = User.getUsers().Result;
```

Comment: Do not call `.Result`, instead use `await`

Comment: OP don't want to make the method async as described above so no await

Answer (score 6):

> The main thing I don't understand is how to initiate the task from a non async method. Everytime I try to call the task, it wants me to convert that method to an async one. Which in turn would want me to turn any method that calls that one to async. So how are you supposed to start it?

As I describe in my async best practices article, [`async` does "grow" through the code base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). This is natural and should be embraced. Especially on a platform such as UWP, where [blocking on asynchronous code can easily cause deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) as well as earn you an immediate disqualification from the app store.

In the simplest situations, the `async` growth stops at an asynchronous event handler, which is `async void`. If you're doing MVVM-based development, there are other considerations; I cover these in a three-part MSDN article series on [async MVVM development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

If you have an existing codebase, you may also find my [article on brownfield async helpful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

Comment: While not the answer I was hoping for, it is probably the answer I need in the long run, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Async Best Practices MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Async code does tend to infect an entire codebase. You could run the task synchronously with Task.Wait. This is not recommended though. You could also send it to a background thread with Task.Run, but of course, then you cannot easily retrieve any results.

Comment: According to your article I should just use async all the way?  What about methods that aren't async?  Can I run non async code as async?

Comment: @evilsushi You could run synchronous code in an async method, yes. As mentioned, you could launch a thread on the threadpool with Task.Run and segment the async tasks from your synchronous tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will have to read the article more and figure the best way to proceed.